# Laravel 5.4 - How to use EDI Vendor Library

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have installed EDI Library through composer command.

Library Link.
https://github.com/php-edifact/edifact

But in this, they did not give how to register your library in App file.

So can please help me how to register it. They are giving examples of how to use this.
I am just writing simple code.

```
   $x = [1,5,8,9];
   $c = new Parser($x);
```

But the above code is giving an error.

> Class 'Parser' not found

Answer (score 0):

Try using `new EDI\Parser($x)`. You need to tell php in what namespace to find the class you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your command prompt

```
composer require sabas/edifact
```

Use in the top of the file like:

```
namespace EDITest;
use EDI\Parser;
```